# Cannot Create a New Project in VS Code SF (macOS) Catalina

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am unable to create a new project in VS code in macOS . I was able to create a new repository  but i am getting the below error when when using >SFDX:Create New Project.

```
sfdx force:project:create --projectname xxxxxx --outputdir /Users/xxxx/Desktop --template standard
ERROR running force:project:create:  Command failed with ENOENT: 
npm root -g --prefix /Users/xxxxx/Desktop/.yo-repository --loglevel error
spawnSync npm ENOENT
```

Comment: Did you recently upgrade? Have you been able to create SFDX projects before this? Try the `sfdx update` to make sure your SFDX CLI is up to date and then try again

Comment: Hi , I did that twice but still same error .

Comment: Can you try running VS code in admin,root mode. If that works, it is probably a permission issue.

Comment: What is the `npm root` output for you? And `npm root -g`. Are you able to execute any other `npm` commands (e.g. `npm install`)? Also, did you try to create a project through CLI, not VSCode?

Answer (score 3):

Even I am was getting this error... and I have resolved this by installing latest node from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and I am able to create project and as well other component.

Make sure restart your system after download.

Comment: Thank you, It worked for me.